# How to calculate induced current?

Tags: electromagnetism, ohms-law

Suppose we have a closed loop with two resistors in series and at particular moment in time the induced emf was two volts .i want to know why do we use ohm's law in calculating the induced current ?

Comment: Simple answer is that we use ohm's law because to the best of human knowledge it is a mathematical relationship which precisely represents reality.  The relative certainty with which we've been able to verify this causes us to refer to it as Ohm's "Law" rather than ohm's "Theorem".  Were you intending to ask how Ohm's law was originally theorized or how to experimentally verify it, or perhaps for an explanation of what it means?

Answer (score 1):

> i want to know why do we use ohm's law in calculating the induced
>   current ?

Current isn’t induced; voltage is induced as per Faraday’s law of induction and, as a result of voltage being induced (by the changing magnetic field), then the current that may flow is defined by the induced voltage and the impedance of the circuit i.e. Ohm’s law.

At DC use resistance and for an AC induced voltage use the reactance and resistance and remember to consider that the wire in which the voltage is induced has self-inductance.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to **induce** a voltage in a loop, that loop having one side parallel to a long wire, and the wire and the loop are in the same plane, then you can use this formula

Vinduce = [MUo * MUr * Area / (2 * PI * Distance)] * dI/dT

where we avoid using natural-logs in the equation by assuming the
separation of the wire and the loop is large compared to the sides of the loop. If these assumpions are wrong, you'll have a 2;1 or 3:1 error, but you'll still get a good idea of the size of the induced voltage, which lets you ponder the size of any magnetic-field interference.

How to use this? assume the dI/dT is 2,000 amps per microsecond
(the current is being switched by IGBTs in a massive motor speed controller, perhaps for a ore-grinding mill)

Let the distance be 4 centimeters. Let the area be of the GROUND plane size of the SpeedController PCB board.

What are the numbers?
With MUo of 4 * pi * 1.0e-7, and MUr = 1 (air, copper), we have

Vinduce = 2e-7 * Area/Distance * dI/dT

Vinduce = 2e-7 * 0.1meter * 0.1meter / 0.04meters * 1e+9 amp/sec

Vinduce = 2e-7 * 0.010 /  0.04 * 1e+9

Vinduce = 2 * 0.01/0.04 * e-7 * e+9= 0.5 * 100 = 50 volts

Thus, before any induced eddy currents that oppose and almost
null the incoming magnetic field, there is 50 volts imposed
on the **sheet** of copper, the Ground plane.

Given 0.000500 ohms (500 microOhms) per square of standard thickness PCB copper foil, the eddy current easily reaches the level of 50/0.0005 = 50 * 2,000 = 100,000 amps to cancel the incoming Hfield.